# Please suggest me which RTOS can be integrated with ROS?

Tags: ros, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am working on a 7- axis robot in which each joint is controlling by a BLDC motor with the help of Elmo gold whistle drive. The motor drive is using Ethercat  as a communication interface using SOEM drivers. Now, coming to the Ethercat communication part, is it necessary to use RTOS to avoid packet loss or can SOEM driver it-self can take care about the transmission and packet loss?  What is the role of RTOS, if it is necessary to integrate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/247492/please-suggest-me-which-rtos-can-be-integrated-with-ros?/) by [TraiBo](https://answers.ros.org/users/28181/traibo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 146 on 2016-11-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is possible to use SOEM to control a number of EtherCAT slaves without an RTOS. This is done on the KUKA youbot for example:

https://github.com/youbot/youbot_driver

Since the Master is in control of the EtherCAT cycle, package loss should not be a problem. However, on a general-purpose OS (non-RTOS), such as Ubuntu with mainline Kernel, you will experience control jitter. In some cases, the EtherCAT slaves expect a new control message every few milliseconds. And if they do not receive the message in time, they will shut down. This behavior is entirely slave dependant.

---

Originally posted by [Jan Carstensen](https://answers.ros.org/users/28461/jan-carstensen/) with karma: 66 on 2017-10-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0